# Помогите, пожалуйста, хочу переделать данную функцию с оплатой из Reply кнопки в Inline. Не получается.Библиотека aiogram3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

```
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'оплата услуг') 
async def buy_handler(message: Message):
    invoice_data = await make_request(
        url="https://api.cryptomus.com/v1/payment",
        invoice_data={
            "amount": "0.5",
            "currency": "USD",
            "order_id": str(uuid.uuid4())
        },
    )

    asyncio.create_task(
        check_invoice_paid(invoice_data['result']['uuid'],
                           message=message))

    await message.answer(f"Ссылка на оплату: {invoice_data['result']['url']}")
```